# Intersection number and associated reduced scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Assume that $X$ is a scheme over an algebraic closed field $k$. $Y$ is a irreducible curve on $X$ with generic point $y$ and $Y$ is proper.

$Y_{red}$ is its reduced scheme. Then for any invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$, can we prove that $(\mathcal{L}\cdot O_Y)=length(O_{Y,y})(\mathcal{L}\cdot O_{Y_{red}})$.

$(\mathcal{L}\cdot \mathcal{F})$ is the intersection number between $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ where the support of $\mathcal{F}$ is 1-dimensional. And it’s defined by the leading coefficient of $n$ in the euler characteristic of $\mathcal{L}^n\otimes\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $(\mathcal{L}\cdot\mathcal{O}_Y)$?

Comment: @Mohan I just want to say intersection number. I think your notation is right.

Comment: $\mathcal O_Y$ is not a line bundle on $X$.

Comment: @MooS You don‘t need it to be a line bundle. To make an intersection number like this make sense, we only need a sheaf whose support is 1-dimensional.

Comment: By my notation, you mean $(\mathcal L;\mathcal O_Y)$ then.

Comment: @MooS I am not sure since I didn’t see your notation before. But as long as you can understand it, it’s right.

Comment: @MooS I think I should add some explanation for this.

Comment: Well for me it is defined via the euler characteristic of $\mathcal L^n \otimes \mathcal O_Y$. Another common notation would be $(\mathcal L \cdot Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clearing the notation, the answer is positive. This is a basic result about how to compute the intersection numbers on irreducible and reduced components, see Proposition 1.2.5iii) in [these lecture notes](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~ein/DFEM.pdf).

Comment: That’s really a good explanation without just using some machinary of EGA.

Comment: I got a problem with this notes, how could we know that on an integral scheme with dimension r, if two sheafs are isomorphic at the generic point, then the coker and ker are with support of dimension less that r?

Comment: A proper closed subset of an irreducible space has lower dimension. This is just topology.